# copy-of command doesn't find node to copy, what is the behavior?

Tags: xml, xslt

What happens when `copy-of` doesn't find the node to copy, because it doesn't exist? It simply does nothing? Or raise an error? It looks like the first, but I am not sure about it...

Comment: If you have a Saxon EE license oXygen or Altova where you can run schema-aware XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, then I think that at least Saxon EE (used by oXygen) will emit warnings for XPath expressions that, according to the used XML schema for the XML input, don't select anything in the context node, see http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema-aware.html

Comment: Yes, it does nothing. Or as the spec puts it "The result of evaluating the instruction is a sequence of items corresponding one-to-one with the supplied sequence, and retaining its order." So if the supplied sequence is empty, then the result sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. If you give it an XPath that selects nothing, then it does nothing. No errors or exceptions. There simply isn't anything to copy.